# Не работает условие в php?

Tags: php

Пытаюсь вывести контент на нужную страницу но условие не работает.

Есть код

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  $access = AccessPage::getIDByUsername($_SESSION['username']);
  foreach($access->id_page as $p_id) {
    $u = AccessPage::getUrlPages($p_id);
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === $u) {
      $u = PrivilegedUser::getByUsername($_SESSION['username']);
      foreach($u->roles as $r_id) {
        $c = Content::getContent($r_id, $p_id);
        foreach($c->contents as $content) {
          eval('?>' . $content);
          print ob_get_clean();
        }                
      }
      // break;
    } 
    elseif ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !== $u) {
      // header( 'Location: '.str_replace('/', '', $u), true, 301 );
      ob_end_flush();
      // break;
    } 
    else {
      echo '<div class="row">';
        echo '<p class="h3" id="h3">Доступ закрыт!</p>'."\n";
      echo '</div>';
    }
  }
}
```

В переменную `$access` получаю объект класса с ассоциативным массивом `id` страниц

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
```

Получаю его с помощью `foreach` и передаю id в другой клаcc который отдает мне в ответ `url`ы страниц для каждого из `id`.

Это пример `url`ов для каждого `id`

```
1 - /index-dev.php
2 - /map.php
3 - /csv.php
```

После этого условие в php перестает работать.

Например: я нахожусь на странице index-dev.php и мне нужно показать контент на этой странице. Если такой `url` в базе для этого пользователя есть, то нужно показать контент. Если такого `url`а в базе для этого пользователя нет, то нужно выполнить редирект на другую доступную страницу или показать текст пользователю что ему доступ запрещен. Пробовал `break` но тогда не работают редирект. Как мне добиться правильной работы условия.

Comment: какое из 3х условий у вас не работает? и какие данные на вход подаются? пробовали смотреть?

Comment: Если оставлять всё в таком виде как есть тогда первое условие срабатывает а в конце страницы появляются две записи "Доступ запрещен". Если раскомментировать строчку `header( 'Location: '.str_replace('/', '', $u), true, 301 );` то тогда всегда редиректит на другую страницу. А с `break` работает только первое условие

Comment: У вас в коде есть управление выводом (функции ```ob_```), в частности в коде есть сбросы и отключение буферизированного вывода, но нет его начала, поэтому совершенно не понятно что именно у вас будет выведено на экран. плюсом ob_end_flush(); в вашем исполнении должно выкинуть всё что помещено в буфер и никуда это не выводить.

Comment: `ob_start();` указан так в самом начале страницы. без него почему-то не работал редирект) Сообщение об ошибки из логов к сожалению не сохранил

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке я и так прекрасно знаю то которое вы получаете без ob_... но досих пор не понятно что именно у вас не работает, понятно только что не в условии проблема.

Comment: Редирект может не работать в случае, если заголовки ответа уже отправлены, это происходит в момент с самым первым выводом, например вызов оператора echo. Есть функция headers_sent https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.headers-sent.php , которая показывает были ли отправлены заголовки.

Comment: убрал `ob_start();` и решил отказаться от редиректа. Но тогда при переходе на другие страницы всё равно появляется N-ое кол-во "Доступ запрещен" и затем показывает контент для этой страницы. полагаю что вычитываются урлы страниц и срабатывает второе условие с запретом. а затем находит урл из списка и выводит по нему контент

Answer (score 0):

В описании:

> Это пример urlов для каждого id
>
> 1 - /index-dev.php
> 2 - /map.php
> 3 - /csv.php

Вот тут

```
$u = AccessPage::getUrlPages($p_id);
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === $u) {
```

вы используете строгое сравнение (`===`) массива со строкой, как я понимаю из описания. Это условие никогда не будет выполнено

Comment: Так ведь переменная `$u` равна допустим `/index-dev.php` и если я нахожусь на `/index-dev.php` и сравниваю с `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` то условие работает для этой страницы. Но у меня же есть еще другие `if` и они для других `url` тоже отрабатывают. Получается так что первое условие выполнилось, и выполнился код для него, а в переменной `$u` появилось `/map.php` и тогда срабатывает редирект который мне становится уже не нужен если страница на которой я нахожусь есть в таблице. Может стоит искать `url` в таблице только один, который будет соответствовать `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`?

Comment: значит я неправильно понял _Получаю его с помощью foreach и передаю id в другой клаcc который отдает мне в ответ urlы страниц для каждого из id_ Из предложения сделал вывод, что их много)))